# Disable and enable the button when changing the drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image: disable and enable using onchange event is not working check the image]

My `onchange` event does not turn on the enable on the button at the first, 3, 5, and so on but i think my code is current here is my code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary disabled" id="next"  >Generate Report</button>
```

These are the drop downs

My Jquery

```
$("#advertiserId,#brandId,#campaignId").on('change',function(){
    if ($("#advertiserId").val()   && $("#brandId").val()  && $("#campaignId").val() ) 
    {
        $("#next").removeClass('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#next").addClass('disabled');
    }    
});
```

The drop down ids

`advertiserId`, `brandId`, `campaignId`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post your HTML?

Comment: What ever plugin you are using, you should read the DOC. I guess it is using custom events. Or maybe you need to delegate event. Anyway, you have to provide minimalistic sample in question itself to replicate issue

Comment: i've tried it many times it does not work ,i have no idea why cause is not the first time i use this method but it worked and it is still working

Comment: Its working check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/wu5he7Lg/

Comment: @FatalError You are using select-Elements, in the jsfiddle, thats OK, but he is talking about Dropdown-menus (basically unordered-list Elements with a button attached to it), these don't have 'change'-Events

Comment: Reginwaldt, can you post your HTML?  Can't troubleshoot this without it.  @maze-le, how can you be sure he's using bootstrap dropdowns and not <select class="form-control">?  Without seeing the markup, it's just an assumption...

Comment: @VCode I assumed it, because he used the word 'drop-down' in the Headline

Comment: @maze-le, it's a fair assumption, but selects are often referred to as drop-downs as well. I'm just saying, there's no way to give a definitive answer here without knowing the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap Dropdown-menus dont fire a 'change'-event, they are clicked... You should handle the 'click'-Event.

[Look at this for an example...](http://www.bootply.com/64302)

[Here are the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events), there are more events, that are specific for Bootstrap...

The appropriate one for you would be:

> `show.bs.dropdown`    This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.

Comment: These events should work for you, just read the bootstrap-documentation on that matter (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage)

Comment: This doesn't seem like what the OP is looking for.  I may be wrong, but it looks like he's trying to disable the button unless all three dropdowns have a selected value.  The show event won't accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Those dropdown menus don't look like the dropdown in the bootstrap.

So I assume it is a selection element.

The problem could be with your version of jQuery or with what you put in the value of the option element inside the selection element.

For instance, if the option has no value

```
<option>first Option</option>
```

this will behaviour as true for the if-statement. So you should set the value as follows:

```
<option value="">first Option</option>
```

I tried some stuff here:
https://jsfiddle.net/s82zcg4y/